# Matlab Gaussian elimination routine for 2 by 2 matrix

Tags: matlab-guide

I need to write a M-file (script or function) that computes and displays the upper triangular matrix. The code should then use the upper triangular matrix to solve a set of linear simultaneous equations.

Comment: What do you have so far, and do you have some example input and output?

Comment: f=[1,1];
n=20;


for n=1:20
    f(1,2*n)=f(1,1*n)+f(1,n),
end